# Convert some UIImages into a GIF file image

Tags: iphone, ios

in iOS, I need to programly convert some png images into a gif image , and make ensure the output gif format image's size as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do this in code and not on your Mac, right?

The first thing I would try is the [ImageIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/) framework. It can convert png files into CGImageRef objects and then export the CGImageRefs to gif files.

Comment: He wants to do it the other way around :P

Comment: @EricS Yes, what i want is to convert some png files to a gif file.

Comment: ImageIO can do it either way. I fixed my answer to specify the correct order.

Comment: @EricS  Thanks for your answer. I will try it. And actually, i worry about that the exported gif file will be too large.

Comment: Only one way to find out. Try ImageIO first and, if the files are too big, you'll probably need to find an open source GIF library or write your own. GIF doesn't handle 24-bit images as well as PNG, so if the source image has more than 256 colors in it you may have issues.